# How can I play multiple animations one by one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character with a animator controller.
And I have 12 fbx animation files I downloaded from Mixamo.com it's the Pro Magic Pack.

The question is should I drag each animation one by one to the animator controller and then add transitions between each animation state ? Or making a blend tree ?

And this is the script I'm using now and I want that the animator in index 2 (animators[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ0TK.jpg)) after "Idle" to start playing on him all the 12 animations.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator[] animators;
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public bool slowDown = false;

    private bool endRot = false;
    private Vector3 center;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        center = target.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;

        for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(animators[2].transform.position, target.position);

        for(int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[2].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(animators[2].transform.position, center, 0);
        }

        if (slowDown)
        {
            if (distanceFromTarget < 10)
            {
                float speed = (distanceFromTarget / 10) / 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
                {
                    animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
                }
            }
        }

        if (distanceFromTarget < 5f)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                animators[i].SetBool("Idle", true);
            }

            if (!endRot)
            {
                Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
                float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(
                        goalRotation,
                        animators[0].transform.localRotation);
                float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

                // use axis of Vector3.down to keep angles positive for ease of use
                animators[0].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angleThisFrame);
                animators[1].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);

                // We end if we rotated the remaining amount.
                endRot = (angleThisFrame == angleToGoal);
            }
            {
                animators[0].SetBool("Rifle Aiming Idle", true);
                animators[1].SetBool("Rifle Aiming Idle", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I have all the animations in the animator controller let's say they are added with transitions how do I loop them in the script and make them to run one by one?

UPDATE:

This is a screenshot of the animation files I want to play one by one from the script: From standing 1H cast spell 01 to Standing 2H Magic Attack 05:

[image: Animation files]

Next screenshot is the current animator controller with the states I have already and some parameters: From Walk to Idle (HumanoidWalk to HumanoidIdle) And I want that if it's Idle then start playing all the animations files:

[image: States animator controller]

So in the script after the character in animators[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ0TK.jpg) is in Idle then start playing the animations on this animator (animators[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ0TK.jpg))

But this are the animation files on the hard disk. Should I add them to the animator first ? Make transition between each animation ? And how to run them one by one in the script once animators[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ0TK.jpg) is in idle ?

Comment: you can loop them all by having one transition from the last animation back to the first one ;)

Comment: @derHugo I have 12 animations how they are all connected if I loop over only the last and first one ? (And I have also other states animations in this controller not only this 12 I want to loop over). And do I need first to add all the 12 animations to the controller and make transitions between them all ?

Comment: I think in order to give you a complete advice it would be great to have more information about your specific use case and maybe a screenshot of your current state machine setup.

Comment: @derHugo Updated now my question with screenshots and what I want to do.

Comment: I would actually use a different approach for that: leave this "animator2" as it is like a kind of "main controller". Than add all your twelve animations to another animator one level below the first. There I would just connect all animations by transition on time 1 and loop them by one transition back to the first state. Than in your animator2 you just switch this second animator on (enabled) and off. If this fits for you and you need more details on this approach let me know I could write an answer but so far I'm not sure if this answers your question

Comment: Or you could probably also make it a "Sub StateMachine"

Comment: @derHugo I will try the Sub StateMachine idea first and will see if I will need help. Thank you for the ideas.